# How to force django app to not serve a subdomain

Tags: django, dns, subdomain, django-urls

I have two separate django applications one for whole site and second for web shop. My main app is under http://www.sitedomain.com . Now I would like to run web shop under http://www.sitedomain.com/shop . Is there a way to force the main project not to serve this subdomain and make the shop application run only under subdomain ?

---

EDIT

Tried solution from the answer, but still all links with /shop are caught by main application. What more there are multiple problems with it's urls. Mos of them does not work now.

My URLS:

```
# Django 
urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url('^accounts/login/?$', login, {"template_name" : "admin/login.html"}, name='auth_login'),
    url('^accounts/logout/?$', logout, name='auth_logout'),
    (r'^favicon\.ico$', 'django.views.generic.simple.redirect_to', {'url': '/media/theme/img/s4lfav.ico'}),
    (r'^admin/(.*)', admin.site.root),
    (r'^jsi18n/$', 'django.views.i18n.javascript_catalog', {'packages': ('django.conf') }),
    (r'^media/(?P<path>.*)$', 'django.views.static.serve', {'document_root': os.path.join(DIRNAME, "media"), 'show_indexes': True }),
)

# Login / Logout
urlpatterns += patterns('django.contrib.auth.views',
    url('^login/?$',  "login",  { "template_name" : "login.html" },  name='login'),
    url('^logout/?$', "logout", { "template_name" : "logged_out.html" }, name='logout'),
)

# Contact form
urlpatterns += patterns('contact_form.views',
    url(r'^contact$', "contact_form", { "form_class" : ContactForm }, name='contact_form'),
    url(r'^sent$', direct_to_template, { 'template': 'contact_form/contact_form_sent.html' }, name='contact_form_sent'),
)

# Sitemaps
urlpatterns += patterns("django.contrib.sitemaps.views",
    url(r'^sitemap.xml', 'sitemap', {'sitemaps': {"pages": PageSitemap}})
)

# Robots
urlpatterns += patterns('django.views.generic.simple',
    (r'^robots.txt', 'direct_to_template', {'template': 'robots.txt'}),
)


urlpatterns += patterns("manage.views",
    url(r'^manage$', "site", name="manage_site"),
    url(r'^manage$', "site", name="manage_site"),
)

# SITE
urlpatterns += patterns('views',
    url(r'^search', "search", name="search"),
    #url(r'^/$', "base_view", name="index_view"),
    #url(r'^/(?P<slug>.*)', "index_view", name="index_view"),
    url(r'^(?P<slug>.*)$', "index_view", name="index_view"),
    url(r'^$', "index_view", name="index_view"),
    #url(r'^/', "index_view", name="index_view"),
)

# Manage
urlpatterns += patterns('manage.views',
    url(r'^manage/applications$', "applications", name="applications"),
    url(r'^manage/install-application/(?P<name>\w+)$', "install_application", name="install_application"),
    (...)
```

Answer (score 2):

Explicitly list all supported urls of the main app in its url.py, instead of using wildcards on the toplevel.

Comment: and dose SITE_URL influence anything at all ? Or it's just for the Site's middleware ?

Comment: and what about index view, set it under '/' ? Cuz if it'll be set for '$' I'm not getting enywhere.

Comment: I don't know what SITE_URL is. It seems to have no relevance in Django (at least not in the current versions).

Comment: I don't know, for me it doesn't seem to work at all. Main view is caught only with `r'^(?P<slug>.*)$'` even though link contains nothing more. What more link to management works with `r'^manage$'` and only when it's on top of urls. But nothing with `manage/...` does not. And finally django still tries to catch /shop :(